# Processing time of a working holiday visa in New Zealand

Tags: visas, new-zealand, working-holiday

I have a flight to New Zealand towards the end of April. I am eligible for the Working Holiday visa as an EU citizen, and would like to apply. No official average processing time is given for the Working Holiday visa by the NZ government as far as I can see, but it appears that it normally takes around two weeks. Anecdotally I know of people receiving the visa approval within a working week.

Would it be acceptable to NZ authorities for me to state that I intend to travel towards the end of April, or should I book a different flight? I understand that if they do not approve my application by my date of travel I should change my travel plans.

I am in French Polynesia and do not currently have a mobile phone number. Would it be worth getting a mobile phone number solely for the purpose of the application?

I have also visited NZ recently as a tourist if this is pertinent.

Comment: You can state your intention to travel if you want, but be aware that NZ immigration won't take any notice of it and won't expedite your visa application at all.  I've been through the NZ visa process several times now, with both my wife's visas being issued in under 4 days but my visa taking 4 weeks - but neither of these visas are working holiday visas.

Answer (score 1):

You can state whatever you want for the date of travel, but all visas generally advise you don't book your trip until you get your visa approved.

One [Visa specialist](https://www.visafirst.com/en/new_zealand_working_holiday_visa_info.asp) suggests you apply *at least* two weeks in advance of departure to avoid problems.